# How to make a reverse proxy with next.js

Tags: javascript, proxy, next.js, reverse-proxy

I would like to create a reverse proxy for the GeForce NOW website using Next.js, but I can't figure it out.

```js
module.exports = {
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/:slug',
        destination: 'https://play.geforcenow.com/:slug',
      },
    ]
  },
}
```

That's what I have based on the docs, but it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work using this in vercel.json:

```json
{
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "(.*)",
      "dest": "https://play.geforcenow.com$1"
    }
  ]
}
```